# Manipulando Excel no Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Estou fazendo uma aplicação no Visual Studio com Visual Basic.
Esta aplicação servirá para consumir dados de um Webservice.

Tenho um problema com uma dessas Webservices, o que acontece é o seguinte:

Eu consegui pegar os dados de uma Web Service e salvar em uma planilha em Excel, criando este arquivo em Excel e tudo. Porém existe um outro Web service que depende de uma informação contida nesta planilha criada. 
Esta informação fica em uma coluna com o nome de **Sequencia**.

No caso o que eu preciso:

- A quantidade de células e variáveis.
- Preciso abrir esta planilha
- Preciso que seja feito um Loop onde o Range se inicia na célula (
  exemplo: "A4" )

O código copia o valor desta célula em uma variável acrescentando uma virgula e vá para a próxima célula até achar uma vazia.

Abaixo segue uma explicação:

Supondo que estes sejam os dados da Planilha:

```
A4 = 1    
A5 = 2    
A6 = 3    
A7 = 4
```

No caso quero que a variável receba os valores das células A4 até A7, pois da A8 em diante não existem dados.

A variavel é **Sequencia** do tipo String e preciso que ela fique assim:

```
Sequencia = 1,2,3,4
```

Como posso fazer isso ? Lembrando que estou programando em Visual Basic no Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Vai depender da biblioteca que você usa, não programei em Visual Basic, mas fiz isso em .Net

Segue o exemplo em c#:

```
//starting
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(stream);

var tab= 1;
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.ElementAt(tab);

var row = 4;
var column = 1;
var value = ws.Cells[row, column].Value

var result = "";

while(!string.IsNullOrEmpity(value)){

  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
  {
    result += ","
  }

  result += value
  row++;

  value = ws.Cells[row, column].Value
}

//end
```

Nesse caso eu estou usando ExcelPackage passando a stream do arquivo que você abriu, pode usar outra biblioteca para abrir o arquivo, como ReaderStream.

Espero que isso te ajudo um pouco.

Comment: Boa noite Wallison, agradeço o retorno e fiquei surpreso por ser tão rapido. Porém não entendi nada pois não manjo de C#. Estou desenvolvendo em Visual Basic e para manipular o Excel eu usei a referencia Microsoft Excel 12 Object Library. Tenho experiencia em VBA para Acces. Já fiz alguns programas que estão ativos até hoje. Porém pela facilidade de adaptação, estou migrando para Visual Basic. Se puder me ajudar com o Código em Visual Basic eu agradeço. Mas obrigado mesmo assim